# A new PSE member with square reputation

Tags: mathematics

(For those viewing this, this is asked from the time when upvotes on question leads to +5 rep.)

A new Puzzling Stack Exchange member (reputation = 1) asked a good question.
He got a square number upvotes, and a square number downvotes.
(more Upvotes than Downvotes)
So, His reputation is a square number below 500.

Then he answered a question, and got good responses.
Again, he got a square number upvotes, and a square number downvotes.
(more Upvotes than Downvotes)
Again, his reputation now is a square number, but still not more than 500.

How many upvote and downvote he get after asking? 
Then, How many upvote and downvote he get after answering?

**Bonus Question**
: How if he answer first before asking?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the beginning, when he asks he gets

> 64 upvotes and 16 downvotes ending up with 289 rep = 17$^2$ rep

and then after he answers the question, he gets

> 16 upvotes and 4 downvotes ending up with 441 rep = 21$^2$ rep

so we are done!! :)

---

*For the Bonus:*

After answering he gets

> 49 upvotes and 25 downvotes ending up with 441 rep = 21$^2$ rep

and then after asking he gets

> 9 upvotes and 1 downvote ending up with 484 rep = 22$^2$ rep

---

**EDIT: HOW I FIGURED IT OUT**

> The riddle never said anything about having to use pencil and paper so I made an assumption and assumed that both numbers were less than 200. Then I wrote a short C++ program and tested all possibilities, ending up with both my answers. Total time taken: 4 min and 30 sec.

Answer (score 11):

We first write the equation as

> $5x^2 - 2y^2 = z^2-1$

We can solve this mathematically by using the fact that

> all perfect squares are $0,1, 4\mod 8$.

This means we can rewrite the equation mod 8 as

> $5 \cdot \text{(0,1, or 4)} - 2 \cdot \text{(0,1, or 4)} = \text{(0,3,7)}$

Checking all cases for the parentheses, we find that the only cases that work are

> (0,0,0), (0,4,0) and (1,1,3)

The first and second solution mean

> x is a multiple of 4, and y is a multiple of 2

and the third solution means

> x and y are both odd.

Checking all perfect squares of these forms, we find the only possible solution is

> 64 upvotes and 16 downvotes, giving 289 reputation.

Similarly for the second part, the equation is

> $10x^2 - 2y^2 = z^2-289$

Taking mod 8 we get

> $10 \cdot \text{(0,1, or 4)} - 2 \cdot \text{(0,1, or 4)} = \text{(0,3,7)}$

giving the solutions

> (0,0,0) (0,4,0) (4,4,0) (4,0,0) and (1,1,0)

The first four solutions mean that

> x and y are both even

and the fifth means that

> x and y are both odd.

Once again, checking all possibilities, we end up with

> 16 upvotes and 4 downvotes, bringing his reputation total to 441.

Comment: the power of elliptic curve theory!