# How to use the numbers 3, 5, 6, and 7 to get 100?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Any mathematics symbols and processes to use the numbers 3, 5, 6, and 7 once each to get 100.

Comment: Once each? Or any combination? I have a couple using more than one of each ... :o)

Comment: Clearly too broad.  See also [Handling underspecified “Make <this number> from <these digits>” questions](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6234/handling-underspecified-make-this-number-from-these-digits-questions) on our Meta.

Answer (score 13):

> $\sqrt{7^6}-3^5$    ...need more characters

Comment: Pretty! ...need more characters

Answer (score 7):

> $100=(57+3)/.6$ if decimal point is allowed.

Answer (score 7):

With the numbers in order:

> $\frac{(3!)! - 5!}{6 \mod 7}$

EDIT: Added some "any processes" answers, some sillier than others:

> $76 - 3 + 5 = 100$ ([octal numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal))
>  $S(3*5*7-6)$ ([successor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function))
>  $$-\frac{\log\left[\left(\log\underbrace{\sqrt{\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt6}}}_{100}\right) / \log(3!)\right]}{\log{(7-5)}}$$ ([generic method for obtaining any positive integer with 3,5,6 and 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours), layout borrowed from [ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/58873/36023))

Answer (score 6):

> $(3 + 7) ^ {\left\lceil \frac{6}{5} \right\rceil}$

Comment: no way, thought about getting 2 out of 6 and 5 forever, never thought of that

Answer (score 4):

If the "floor" function is acceptable:

> $\left\lfloor 3\times5\times6.7 \right\rfloor$

Answer (score 2):

> $7!!-5×6/3!$ using double factorial

Answer (score 1):

> 35+67-2 $%The question doesn't say we can't use other digits$

Comment: Where did the 2 come from?

Comment: @Catija It's a "loophole" answer: the question doesn't say *only* those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

> ${{6}\choose{3}} * 5 + \dot{7}$

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what each step here means? I get that C(6,3) is combinations, but what's the apostrophe supposed to be? Is it a derivative?

Comment: Yeah, that's it... Derivation of constant trick

Comment: I've updated it to use MathJax, if that's alright with you.

Answer (score 1):

> $$ \left \lceil 357 * \sin(-6) \right \rceil = 100$$